# Interpretation of logistic regression results

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation

I have a database that looks like this

```
Firm  Event  Dummy_Event  Dummy_Ev16     Year       Info       Dummy14      Dummy15     Dummy16
1       0         0           0          2014        x           1             0           0
1       0         0           0          2015        x           0             1           0
1       1         1           1          2016        x           0             0           1
2       0         0           0          2014        x           1             0           0
2       1         1           0          2015        x           0             1           0
3       0         0           0          2014        x           1             0           0
3       0         0           0          2015        x           0             1           0
3       0         0           0          2016        x           0             0           1
4       1         0           0          2014        x           1             0           0
```

Basically, I have analysed some firms for the years 2014-2016, eliminating them if an event happens.
I have also added some year dummies at the end (equal to 1 if we are in a specific year), to implement a year fixed effects model.
Dummy_Event becomes equal to 1 if we have a certain "event A" (there are two possible events), while Dummy_Ev16 becomes equal to 1 if the "event A" takes place in 2016.

I want to perform the following regression

```
Event ~ Info + Dummy_Event + Dummy_Ev16 + Dummy14 + Dummy15 + Dummy16
```

To check both how much "event A" and "event A" in 2016 explain the total number of events (and if it is more likely to have event A or event B, in general, and in 2016).

The question is: if from the regression I obtain the following coefficients:
Dummy_Event = +7
Dummmy_Ev16 = +5
How can I interpret those coefficients? Is event A more likely to happen with respect to event B?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal?  Where are the precise estimands?  What do you mean by "eliminate them if an event happens" and why did you do that?

Comment: The goal is to determine the impact of the specific year 2016, and if it determines a higher or lower amount of event A. The companies are no longer part of the sample after the event because I have no use in them

Comment: Please add extra information in comments to the post as an edit. We want posts to be self-contained, not everybody reads comments. Comments also can be deleted.